# How to delete duplicate lines written by page reload?

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter, pageload

I write a log file and it always has a duplicate line (cause by page reloading I guess).

```
userName searched for: 'assembly' at: 3/24/2015 7:32:42 AM
userName searched for: 'assembly' at: 3/24/2015 7:32:43 AM
```

Here is my code for file writing:

```
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.AppendText(Server.MapPath("~/searchlog.txt")))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(userRecord.name + " searched for: \'" + ProcessInputClause + "\' at: " + DateTime.UtcNow);
}
```

What would be a good way to get rid of this? I am thinking of using:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("...");
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("...", lines.Take(lines.Length - 1).ToArray());
```

But this doesn't seem to work...

Comment: PageLoad? Do you mean the callback of an ASP.NET page caused by server side code ? What about preventing it with Page.IsPostBack?

Comment: @Steve my thoughts exactly. However, isn't the search itself a result of a postback?

Comment: Umm... this doesn't look thread-safe. How do you synchronize the logging?

Comment: Yes, the whole scenario is not clear. Perhaps if the OP posts the code around these lines it would be better

Comment: @Luaan, Steve: what you mean by synchronize the logging ? Why do I need so?  I thought all the related processes is stated here, what else you need ?

Comment: Well, you're obviously coding a web application. Multiple users tend to use web applications at the same time. If two requests try to write to the same file at the same time, you're going to have loads of *fun*. You're in a heavily multi-threaded environment, I suggest avoiding shared state (such as writing to a file), or learning a lot more about safe multi-threading :)

Comment: Thats right, its new to me. For this case, what is your approaching ?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't remove any record from your log. You need precisely know what happens in application to be able reproduce application bugs. Removing line from log can hide something very important.

In case there is need remove some duplication from log than there is probably some design smell.

Comment: This log is only to record what user type in a certain box, and a duplicate for a every lines of a long record looks quite ugly. The page reload, I asked here once, they said it is normal.

Comment: than you should log Post method for example. In case two users will find something, you can easily remove one user log record with your approach.

Comment: yeah, introduce quality(clever) log is better than fixing bad log output. Otherwise you will pay big cost for maintenance than

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var previoustext = new HashSet<string>();
File.WriteAllLines(destinationFile, File.ReadLines(sourceFile)
                                        .Where(line => previoustext.Add(line)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the place you write your log since some modules of the page may call your script multiple times while loading one page.

I wouldn't log the search entries what I would do is insert into database the record that have been searched at what time and other info you need so it is even easier to make reports or statistics of searches done on your website.